# How long will it take to rename table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

How long will it take to rename a table with a size of 219 GB?

This is the specification of our server:

- Memory: 65 GB
- Available disk space: 266 GB

---

MySQL Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77

Sorry for the confusion. Our plan is to rename a MySQL table with size of 219 GB.
How long will it take? Do we need to have a large disk space for this migration?

Table's engine: `InnoDB`.

Comment: Renaming a table usually only takes a split second (at least  with the DBMS I work with) - unless the table is locked and your rename is waiting for other transactions to complete.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name

does the size of the table matters?

Comment: an RENAME In MySQL is slow command... When you execute RENAME, you cannot have any locked tables or active transactions. You must also have the ALTER and DROP privileges on the original table, and the CREATE and INSERT privileges on the new table. hard to geuss your time depens on your disk speeds (because an disk temporary table needs to be created) and yes this will comsume more diskspace.. MySQL 5.6 can do some alters very quick not sure if rename is one off them..

Comment: so guys, what can you suggest in renaming a table with disk space of 219 GB?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pE9qGuGp

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no its almost instead just like PostgreSQL or Oracle database... even within MySQL version 5.0.77 check the answer i may include the source code analyse..

Comment: @Katrina.. The answers here of both mine and Michael - sqlbot claim renaming an table is almost an instead operation.

Comment: @raymond what do you mean by "renaming an table is almost an instead operation"

Comment: @Katrina i mean with instead operation that  it will not take lots off time or system resources (diskspace)

Answer (score 20):

Renaming a table in MySQL does not require a temporary table.

There are two statements that perform an equivalent operation.

```
RENAME TABLE t1 TO t2;
ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME TO t2; # as long as no other options to ALTER are also specified
```

Renaming a table acquires a metadata lock on the table which requires that no statements be running against the table, no transactions have row locks, and no transactions are holding on to consistent snapshots of any MVCC versions of the table.

Either style of `RENAME` operation will attempt to acquire the metadata lock and subsequently-started statement impacting the table will block, waiting for the pending metadata lock.

> If you use ALTER TABLE tbl_name RENAME TO new_tbl_name without any other options, MySQL simply renames any files that correspond to the table tbl_name without making a copy.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html</sup>

Note that's a link to the 5.0 documentation, and the 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, and 5.7 all have the same information.

The major delay you could see will come from other sessions preventing the `RENAME` from starting because the locks can't be immediately required.

If you are able to execute a [`FLUSH TABLES table_name;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html) statement and have it return within a few seconds, that should serve as confirmation that the rename operation will complete in a similar amount of time, since it will need the same locks in order to remove any entries in the query cache related to the table, close the table, and clean up some internal structures like the table share object... the table is automatically reopened by the next statement that accesses it... so it gives you a good test of what to expect and would be a good idea to run first, since it's typically going to make the actual rename operation slightly shorter by leaving less work for the rename to do.

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` while waiting for the `FLUSH` to complete (if there's a delay) will give you an idea of things that might get in the way of the rename operation, and you can safely `KILL` the flush if you need to.

Comment: if 0.10 seconds is too slow for the `RENAME`, you can improve the performance by disabling `sync_frm`, at the cost of sacrificing durability in the case of a simultaneous server crash.

Comment: I assume that's meant as sarcasm, which is fair enough if 0.10 seconds is a problem, but the point, of course, is not about the actual rename, which is very quick, but other things like open transactions, other locks, an oversized query cache, and queries in progress can stretch it out substantially, and disrupt the application in the mean time... and the flush is a good test for this.  If the flush is quick, the rename should be quick.   Otherwise, disabling sync_frm is the worst idea I've heard today, but then again, it's still relatively early here.

Comment: @jynus let me geuss one off your hobbies is playing russian roulette??? if you are lucky you can restore corrupted .frm from the general sql log of binary log if you had enabled them.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot +1 btw for the complete explainment.

Comment: @Michael Sarcasm (partially) but true- everything I said is true. In fact, I've had to disable that on testing servers (not on production) with huge fsync fs problems- I think Mac had that problem some time ago when doing a lots of DDLs- common on devel. But yeah, the main problem will be metadata locks, which people do not tend to fully understand- why is my FTWRL blocked and blocking other queries?

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL documention see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rename-table.htmlabout the SQL

```
RENAME table a TO b
```

looks much worst then it accurately is because off the

> When you execute RENAME, you cannot have any locked tables or active
> transactions. You must also have the ALTER and DROP privileges on the
> original table, and the CREATE and INSERT privileges on the new table.

If you read this it looks like MySQL needs to CREATE an new table b copy data from table a into table b (INSERT) and DROP the table a.

Ive analysed the source code off MySQL 5.0.77 behind the SQL command

```
RENAME table a TO b
```

And it looks like an almost instant operation because only the

1. .frm (table definition file)
2. .trg (trigger file)

files needs to be touched (renamed) no actual data copy between tables is needed..
This makes me wonder why you should need the INSERT privilege for this command..

Comment: what is an "instead" operation please?

Comment: thanks that word should have been instant @mcmillab it was a typo

Comment: I just renamed a 110GB table on MySQL 8.0.36 and it did it instantly. It was not being used anymore at the time I renamed it.